# Message delta API failed to return fields if only change is_read field

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, outlook-restapi, microsoft-graph-mail

I use this request to get all changes in messages:

```
GET /users/user_id/mailFolders/folder_id/messages/delta
```

And then use @odata.deltaLink to track next change

But there is a strange thing:

if I only change the message's isRead field, the delta API only returns few fields:

```
{
    "@odata.type": "#microsoft.graph.message",
    "parentFolderId": "xxx",
    "isRead": true,
    "id": "xxx"
}
```

But delta API would normally return all fields like `subject`, `bodyPreview`, `importance`, `parentFolderId`, `conversationId`, etc.

Is it by design or a bug?

Comment: I think its just showing you what changed.  My understanding is that is by design.

Comment: @ChrisJohnson, but only isRead field has this phenomenon, if I only change flag or catagory with this message, it returns all
@ Marc LaFleur, do you have any updates?
thank you guys!